# Notification not being broadcasted to the console?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a notification in laravel that is being saved to the database but it should also broadcast to the client in js so that the notifications dropdown auto-updates with the new notification. Pusher is getting the correct channel ID. The notification dropdown shows the correct notification upon reloading the page but it will not auto-update with the Echo.private method. Nothing shows up in the console. The CSRF token is there and the meta tag with user ID is there as well. Can anyone help me figure out why the notification is not being pushed? Forgot to add that Events are being broadcasted and listened to on public channels just fine. It’s just that notifications won’t work.

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue           from 'vue'
import Notifications from 'vue-notification'


Vue.use(Notifications);

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('orders', require('./components/Orders.vue').default);
Vue.component('support', require('./components/Support.vue').default);
Vue.component('support-messages', require('./components/SupportMessages.vue').default);
Vue.component('signups', require('./components/Signups.vue').default);
Vue.component('signup-messages', require('./components/SignupMessages.vue').default);
Vue.component('notification-dropdown', require('./components/Notifications.vue').default);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        notifications: ''
    },

    created()
    {
        axios.post('/notifications/get').then(response => {
            this.notifications = response.data
        });

        var userId = $('meta[name="userId"]').attr('content');
        Echo.private('App.User.' + userId).notification((notification) => {
            console.log(notification);
            this.notifications.push(notification);

    });
    }

});
```

**Notifications.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="notifications-autoload">
        <div id="notification-dropdown" class="dropdown dropleft dropdown-notifications sw-open">
            <button id="notifications-button" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                 Notifications <span class="badge">{{notifications.length}}</span>
            </button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu notifications">
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                    <div class="dropdown-toolbar">
                        <div v-if="notifications.length > 0" class="dropdown-toolbar-actions">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/notifications/read"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></i> Mark all as read</a>
                        </div>
                        <li v-for="notification in notifications">
                            <a v-on:click="MarkAsRead(notification)" class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ notification.data.message}}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li v-if="notifications.length === 0">
                            There are no new notifications.
                        </li>
                    </div><!-- /dropdown-toolbar -->
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['notifications'],
        methods: {
            MarkAsRead: function(notification)
            {
                var data = {
                    id: notification.id
                };
                axios.post('/notifications/read', data).then(response => {
                    window.location.reload()
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The notifiable type I was using was for App/Admins, so I had to change the Private channel to Echo.private('App.Admins.' + userId).notification((notification). In all of the googling/research I did, I did not once come across anything that mentioned you had to match the notifiable type to the private channel name. It briefly stated it in the Laravel docs, but it was easily overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

For those that have moved all their Models into a "Models" directory (i.e App/Models) will need to update the channel reference to:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

and

```
window.Echo.private('App.Models.User.' + userId).notification((notification) => {
    console.log(notification)
})
```

Comment: This absolutely saved my time. I moved the User model to App\Models, and then broadcasting with notification doesn't work at all. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

---

### How to configure Laravel with Node And Pusher VUE js

Step 1 Install laravel first

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 5.4.*
```

STEP 2 Set Variables change Broadcastserviceprovider

```
we first need to register the App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider. Open 
config/app.php and uncomment the following line in the providers array.

// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider

 We need to tell Laravel that we are using the Pusher driver in the .env file:

  BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

  add pusher Class in config/app.php

 'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class,
```

STEP 3 Add A Pusher to your laravel project

```
 composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

STEP 4 Add following to config/broadcasting.php

```
'options' => [
      'cluster' => env('PUSHER_CLUSTER'),
      'encrypted' => true,
  ],
```

STEP 5 Set Pusher Variable

```
 PUSHER_APP_ID=xxxxxx
 PUSHER_APP_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 PUSHER_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 PUSHER_CLUSTER=xx
```

STEP 6 Install Node

```
 npm install
```

STEP 7  Installl Pusher js

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

STEP 8 uncommnet Following

```
// resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

  import Echo from "laravel-echo"

  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'eu',
   encrypted: true
 });
```

STEP 9 Before you create Migration

```
 // app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
// remember to use
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
  Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
 }
```

Comment: I figured it out. The notifiable type I was using was for App/Admins, so I had to change the Private channel to Echo.private('**App.Admins.**' + userId).notification((notification).

In all of the googling/research I did, I did not once come across anything that mentioned you had to match the notifiable type to the private channel name. It briefly stated it in the Laravel docs, but it was easily overlooked.